# Skipping an iteration in for loop (VBA excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of code in which i would like the for loop to continue to the next value of `i` if the value in a cell is `"nil"` and not execute the commands in the loop. I am unable to figure it out.

```
For i = 2 To n
    If .Cells(i, "G").Value = "nil" Then
        next i
    Else
        mon = month(.Cells(i, "G").Value)
        acctyp = .Cells(i, "P").Value
    end if
next i
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: . . .`i = i + 1`

Comment: Why is your current code not working?

Comment: since the variable mon is an integer i would not take in the month(nil) argument .

Comment: @abinkurian What Vincent means is...  At the moment, if the value is "nil" then it does nothing, essentially running an "empty" loop and skipping to the next `i`.  If your requirements are more complex, and all else fails, just put a label (e.g. `Continue:`) before the `next i`, and then use `GoTo` (e.g. `GoTo Continue`)...

Comment: thanks the goto label worked !

Comment: You really shouldn't need a `GoTo` statement in this though. The `If` should handle it

Comment: Your loop will work fine if you just remove the first `Next i` - replace it with a comment if that helps `'Do Nothing`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/comparison-operators) `<>` means "not equal to":

```
For i = 2 To n
    If .Cells(i, "G") <> "nil" Then
        mon = Month(.Cells(i, "G"))
        acctyp = .Cells(i, "P")
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: @abinkurian - you're welcome . . . just to clarify, there are several comparison operators. [Here is a list](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/comparison-operators).